# How to close popup_menu by python command?

Tags: python

I have a finesta on the fly, is there a python command that closes that "draw" it without having to take any action?
This is the example:

```
def draw(self, context):

    layout= self.layout
    layout.label(text= "My text")

bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(draw, title="My little panel", icon='INFO')
```

Edit:

Upon request, I add details of use.
This popup has some information that is updated during a timer-type modal process, so the panel is constantly drawn with updated data, the problem is that it overlaps with the previous ones, for a comfort I used `bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu()` but the problem is that it does not close

Comment: why do you want to do that? popup menus close when you hover your mouse away...

Comment: Agree with Tareyes, please add any use case. Otherwise `C.window.cursor_warp()` should do it...

Comment: I have updated the answer based on your request

Comment: @brockmann C.window.cursor_warp() this actually moves the cursor always to the same position, but does not close the previous popups

Comment: You can specify any position right? @Pastrokkio

Comment: @brockmann C.window.cursor_warp(x,y)?

Comment: Yep, did you test that? @Pastrokkio

Comment: @brockmann yes I tested this right now, allows you to give the cursor a position, so the panel is always drawn in the same position (which for me is also fine) but just the old popups remain below it

Comment: Could you please add a minimal code example, how do you call both dialogs at once?

Comment: @brockmann  The draw event takes place inside a timer-type modal operator,
def modal (self, context, event): -> if event.type == 'TIMER': -> def draw (self, context)

Comment: Triggered every 2 seconds? Don't get it... sorry @Pastrokkio

Comment: @brockmann I have to have every modal "time loop" updated values in panel, this works, the problem is just the fact that it doesn't close the old panel

Comment: To be honest I personally still don't get what you want :) Anyway, I'm sure the others will, good luck...